# Graphic drawing error in R with leaflet.minicharts library

Tags: r, maps, leaflet

I tried to draw a graph with the following code:

```
 library(leaflet.minicharts)
 library(leaflet)

 data("eco2mix")
 head(eco2mix)
 View(eco2mix)

 library(dplyr)

 prod2016 <- eco2mix %>%
  mutate(renewable = bioenergy + solar + wind + hydraulic,
        non_renewable = total - bioenergy - solar - wind - hydraulic) %>%
 filter(grepl("2016", month) & area != "France") %>%
 select(-month) %>%
 group_by(area, lat, lng) %>%
 summarise_all(sum) %>%
 ungroup()

tilesURL <- "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas        /World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

 basemap <- leaflet(width = "100%", height = "400px") %>%
 addTiles(tilesURL)

 colors <- c("#4fc13c", "#cccccc")

 basemap %>%
    addMinicharts(
    prod2016$lng, prod2016$lat,
    type = "pie",
    chartdata = prod2016[, c("renewable", "non_renewable")], 
    colorPalette = colors, 
    width = 60 *  sqrt(prod2016$total)/
    sqrt(max(prod2016$total)),
    transitionTime = 0)
```

But I get an error:

> Error in addMinicharts(., prod2016$lng, prod2016$lat, type = "pie",
>   chartdata = prod2016[,: unused argument (chartdata =
>   prod2016[,c("renewable", "non_renewable")])

Comment: it works for me. What is your sessionInfo()?

Comment: I have published my session as an answer, too many characters :-)

Comment: you could update your dplyr and leaflet.minicharts and rerun your code.

Answer (score 0):

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_1.1.0            dplyr_0.5.0              leaflet.minicharts_0.1.0 sp_1.2-4
[5] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10     lattice_0.20-35  assertthat_0.2.0 digest_0.6.12    mime_0.5         grid_3.4.0       R6_2.2.0
 [8] jsonlite_1.4     DBI_0.6-1        xtable_1.8-2     magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.2.0   RevoUtils_10.0.4 tools_3.4.0
[15] htmlwidgets_0.8  crosstalk_1.0.0  shiny_1.0.3      yaml_2.1.14      httpuv_1.3.3     compiler_3.4.0   htmltools_0.3.6 
[22] tibble_1.3.0

Comment: Just add this info you just added to your question. You can edit your question. This space is only for answer.